# Is 優しい the opposite of 難しい

Tags: grammar, meaning

From a book:

[image: img1]

As far as I'm concerned, やさしい can mean either easy or gentle. However, the kanji used for each is different: 易しい and 優しい, respectively. That is, you wouldn't use 優しい in あの問題は優しい, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is almost certainly an erratum.

The *Kojien* dictionary explicitly mentions that the meaning of 'easy' is written as 易しい:

`(「易しい」と書く)   簡単である。容易である。`
`今昔物語集10「―・しく手を斬らるるがつたなきなり」「―・い仕事」`
`わかりやすい。「―・い本」`

[Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9B%A3%E5%BA%A6) agrees, for whatever that is worth. What book is this from?

Comment: Sorry for the late response: https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=djydDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Stout+japanese+picture+dictionary+page+27&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiD46Wr1vj0AhUSQzABHSaeATYQ6AF6BAgLEAM#v=onepage&q=Stout%20japanese%20picture%20dictionary%20page%2027&f=false. There's a digital index, click on "Opposites", and scroll down two pages from there.